# Why are the file permissions changed when creating a file with the open system call on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a file with full permission (777) using the `open` system call, but when I do `ls -l` I can see only permission as (755). Could you please tell why file permission is not 777?

**Code**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
        int fd;

        /* Creates a file with full permission*/
        fd = open("test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);

        if (fd = -1)
        {
                return -1;
        }

        close(fd);
}
```

**Output**

```
     $ ls -l
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 2012-09-19 11:55 test
```

Comment: It has to do with the `umask`. See e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Incidentally, the assignment in `if (fd = -1)` should be a comparison `if (fd == -1)`.  However, that only affects the exit status of the program, not the permissions on the created file.

Comment: Also, consider whether your test file really should be executable.  I'd suggest that most often, 0666 permissions are more appropriate than 0777 for a file.  Directories are a different story; there, the execute (access) permission is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a value maintained by the system called the `umask`; it is a property of the process, just like the PID (process ID) or EUID (effective user ID) is.  It will be set to `022` (octal), which indicates that the system should remove the group and other write permission from files that are created.

You can call [`umask(0);`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) before using `open()` so that the mode you specify in `open()` won't be altered.  You should certainly do this to demonstrate that `umask` is the issue. However, it is generally best to let the user's choice of `umask` prevail — I for one get very stroppy if a program doesn't obey my umask setting; it tends not to be used again after I spot and verify the problem.

The shell also has a (built-in) command `umask` which you can use.  The `022` value is a sensible default; most of the time, you do not want just anybody writing to your files.

Answer (score 3):

The permissions of a created file are restricted by the process's current `umask` -- your current `umask` is `022`, so group and world write are always disabled by default. (Which is a good thing, in most cases.) If you really want a group- and world-writable file, you will need to temporarily set `umask(0)` while creating this file (make sure to save the old value returned by the system call, and set it back afterwards!), or "manually" set the file's permissions using `chmod()`.

Answer (score 0):

`umask` will return the original value of the mask, so to reset it temporarily you just need to do

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

mode_t old_mask = umask(0);
...
umask(old_mask);
```

though it would be perhaps preferable to use `fchmod` *after* opening the file - this will avoid the problem of changing process-global state:

```
fd = open("test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);
if (fd < 0) { ... }
int rv = fchmod(fd, 0777);
if (rv < 0) { /* fchmod errored */ }
```