# open() command does not create file with right permissions

Tags: c, file-permissions, user-permissions

I want to run the open() command so that it creates a file if it doesn't exist. As far as the manual goes, you should run it with the `O_CREAT` flag which then requires an additional argument that specifies the permissions for the newly created file.

My problem is, that it doesn't give `outfile` the right permissions. When I run this code:

```
int get_fd_outfile(char *filename)
{
    int fd_outfile;

    fd_outfile = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666); // permissions right?
    if (fd_outfile == -1)
        pipex_error("Error: Could not open output file for writing");
    return (fd_outfile);
}
```

I get a file with the following permissions:
`-rw-r--r-- [...] outfile`. But I want it to have read/write for user, group and others. Why doesn't the octal code `0666` create the right permissions? But the `O_[...]` flags do actually work...

Edit: Maybe it's because I'm on a Mac? I read something about that...

Comment: _"Maybe it's because I'm on a Mac?  I read something about that..."_.  Maybe it is.  What exactly did you read?

Comment: [Does this address your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489525/why-are-the-file-permissions-changed-when-creating-a-file-with-the-open-system-c)

Comment: (If not, comment me and I will retract my vote to close due to duplicate.)

Comment: @0 That's octal `666`, should be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `umask` value, it also plays a role in this:

```
              The effective mode is modified by the process's umask in
              the usual way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode
              of the created file is (mode & ~umask).
```

From https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Or from `man 2 open` on a Mac:

```
     The oflag argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does not exist (by specifying
     the O_CREAT flag).  In this case, open() and openat() require an additional argument mode_t mode; the
     file is created with mode mode as described in chmod(2) and modified by the process' umask value (see
     umask(2)).
```

You can use the `umask` command to see your current value. This is what it looks like for me:

```
$ umask
0022
```

That masks out the `w` for group and other, and matches what you're seeing. You can use the `umask()` system call to change it within the C program, temporarily, or `chmod()` the resulting file afterward.

Comment: That made it clear, thanks!